# Изминение цвета фона в Drawable ресурсе

Tags: android, android-drawable

У меня есть некая `my_drawable.xml`, выглядит она так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/color_chat_task_title" >
    </solid>

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp">
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Вопрос: как я могу в `java` коде изменить в ней цвет фона?

Comment: посмотри [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

### .xml

```
...
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imgShape"
android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
...
```

### .java

```
ImageView imgShape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgShape);
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) imgShape.getBackground();
drawable.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать второй xml файл с другим цветом и установить методом `setBackgroundResource`.